# Should we create a Community FAQ page?

Tags: discussion

Should we add a **Community FAQ** page, similar to this page for Meta Stack Overflow: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow ?

It can have links to the FAQs that have evolved over the years of the existence of Meta Parenting Stack Exchange. Currently, many useful discussions remain scattered across the site, and are not collected systematically.

Comment: I absolutely think we should!

Comment: Note that to create the Community FAQ, that page (as well as the linked pages) should be tagged [tag:faq]. But this tag can **only** be added by moderators. Other users get the error message "'faq' can only be used by moderators". What should the logistics be for tagging the Community FAQ and the linked pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that isn't a lot of votes, but then our community here on meta is pretty small so I do agree that it indicates consensus, so thank you for starting this off.

If you want to make a start at drafting an FAQ page, I or one of the other mods can pop the faq tag onto it, and onto linked pages.